# How to convert a unix time to PostgreSQL' Timstamp without timezome?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I have a PostgreSQL database running on a server which has its time zone set to India's Time Zone (i.e. UTC +5:30)

I have some data in a table which is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "CLOUDDATA"
(
  "CD_Tm_Obs" timestamp without time zone,
  "CD_Avg_Cloud" double precision
)
```

I want to query the data and get the values for a specific time. My Input will be an Unix Timestamp (i.e. Seconds from 1-Jan 1970)

The only way of converting the unix time to Timestamp I have found is this:
`select to_timestamp(TRUNC(CAST(1395036000 AS bigint)))`. But this create a timestamp with timezone. My data is in `timestamp without time zone`, so I don't get any results.

How to convert a unix time to PostgreSQL's Timstamp without timezome?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

I've simplified your query, as you shouldn't need the `TRUNC()`, nor the `CAST()`.

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1395036000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';

SELECT timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval '1395036000 second';
```

For reference, more information can be found at the following links:

- [First
  query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT-TABLE)
- [Second
  query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE)

Comment: Second snippet works also on RedShift.